# Creating a custom function to create individuals using DEAP

Tags: genetic-algorithm, deap

I am using DEAP to resolve a problem using a genetic algorithm. I need to create a custom function to generate the individuals. This function checks the values inside in order to append 0 or 1.

Now I'm trying to register this function on the toolbox.

The function I have written is called *individual_creator(n)*, *n=IND_SIZE* and it returns a vector [].

After creating individuals as a list:

```
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMin)
```

I registered individual and population on my toolbox like the following:

```
toolbox.register("individual", individual_creator, creator.Individual, n=IND_SIZE)

toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
```

Using this code this error appeared: `TypeError: individual_creator() got multiple values for argument 'n'`

Registering individual without using *n* parameter doesn't work either:

`toolbox.register("individual", individual_creator, creator.Individual)`

`TypeError: 'type' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Could someone please help me? I need to create custom individuals using my function and then create the population.

Thank you in advance!